# UIStackView alignment issue

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I want to achieve this requirement

if vertical stack has two label than Text should be centre aligned to image

[image]

and if not than top aligned to Image

[image]

How can I achieve this without writing any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to control the `alignment` of the outer (i.e final stack view which contains both the image and the labels' stack view) stack view.

As you will need to control which labels need to be added to the labels' stack view, I assume you will be doing this programmatically. So basically you'll need:

```
finalStackView.alignment = labelsStackView.arrangedSubviews.count > 2 ? .top : .center
```

---

Here is a complete example which produces the below outputs:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let finalStackView = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "taylor-swift")

        let label1 = UILabel()
        let label2 = UILabel()
        let label3 = UILabel()
        let label4 = UILabel()

        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label1.text = "Hello"
        label2.text = "72 mins"
        label3.text = "Hello 3"
        label4.text = "Hello 4"

        let labelsStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3, label4])
        labelsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labelsStackView.axis = .vertical
        labelsStackView.distribution = .fill
        labelsStackView.alignment = .leading

        finalStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        finalStackView.addArrangedSubview(labelsStackView)
        finalStackView.axis = .horizontal
        finalStackView.distribution = .fill
        finalStackView.alignment = labelsStackView.arrangedSubviews.count > 2 ? .top : .center

        view.addSubview(finalStackView)
        finalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        finalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        finalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        finalStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }


}
```

With the exact code above the output is: 
[image: top aligned stack view]

With 2 labels added to the `labelsStackView`, the output is: 
[image: center aligned stack view]

Answer (score 1):

- Keep the `labels vertical stackview` in a `Horizontal stackView`.
- if you have more than 2 labels, change `Horizontal stackView` alignment to `top` else keep it to `center`.
- Your layout structure be like

```
> main stack view (Horizontal)
 > Image
 > stack view (Horizontal)
   >labels stack view (Vertical)
    > Labels
```